# please help me figure out how to fix this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi'

Tags: python-3.x

The executed command:

```
pip install goodbyecaptcha
```

And the error I get when `pip` goes to `pocketphinx==0.1.15`

```
Collecting pocketsphinx==0.1.15
  Using cached pocketsphinx-0.1.15.tar.gz (29.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-5w4o2xw6\pocketsphinx_28ae123a4f0648b5b85b61f178e07d40\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
          from distutils.command.bdist_msi import bdist_msi as _bdist_msi
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`
```

Please help me to figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install --pre pocketsphinx` and install goodbyecaptcha again.